# Reverse iterating over a &vec versus vec.iter()

Tags: iterator, rust

This works because `Iterator` implements `rev()` where `self` is a `DoubleEndedIterator`:

```
let vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
for x in vec.iter().rev() {
    //Do stuff
}
```

However, if I change `vec.iter().rev()` to `&vec.rev()` it won't compile because:

> ```
> no method named `rev` found for type `std::vec::Vec<i32>` in the current scope
> ```

Furthermore:

> ```
> the method `rev` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `std::vec::Vec<i32> : std::iter::Iterator`, `[i32] : std::iter::Iterator`
> ```

But doesn't a for loop implicitly call [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html)? Is `&vec` or `vec.iter()` considered idiomatic Rust?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're just looping over the `Vec`, then `&vec` is idiomatic.  This works because `&Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator`, which is what the for loop uses.

However if you want to call `Iterator` methods such as `rev`, `filter`, etc., you need an actual `Iterator` (since `Vec` doesn't implement `Iterator`, only `IntoIterator`).

So this:

```
for x in &vec.rev() {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for x in (&vec.rev()).into_iter() {
    ...
}
```

i.e. there's no chance to use `IntoIterator` before trying to call `Iterator` methods.

Answer (score 16):

This is just basic precedence of the `&` operator. In the first case, each method is called in turn:

```
vec.iter().rev()
(vec.iter()).rev() // same
```

In the second case, the `&` binds after all the methods:

```
&vec.rev()
&(vec.rev()) // same
```

Generally, use `&vec` when you can, but when you need to use *iterator adapter methods*, use `iter` or `into_iter`.